# Test performance of a jersey web service

Tags: java, testing, jersey

I just finished my jersey web service and I want to test its performance. The question is how to simulate concurrent requests, number of users that use simultaneously the service , how to determine the max load. I found a tool called [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) but do not know if it is the most suitable for me.

Should you have anything else to suggest, please do as I am a newbie on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your web-service is REST over HTTP?

Pretty much any load-testing tool out there can handle REST calls, with concurrent threads and asserts for error checking. Jmeter is definitely suitable. Here are some how-tos on using Jmeter to test REST services:

[1](http://ecmarchitect.com/archives/2014/09/02/3915)
[2](http://blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter)

Comment: Yes it is rest over http. And the tutorials are exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!